# Can't move windows with Ctrl+Alt+Shift anymore on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcuts

I am using default Ubuntu with Gnome 3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

The shortcut to change workspaces up/down is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow_Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow_Down</kbd>

And adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the combinations move the window with focus to the next (up/down) workspace, regarding the arrow key used.

This shortcut does not work anymore. Why?

Also, maybe related, other shortcuts with <kbd>Shift</kbd> are not working too.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the window management key shortcuts in the system settings (directly accessible with `gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts`), verify that they’re configured to your liking and report back? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is now `Shift`+`Super`+`Page_Up` when it should be `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Arrow_Up`

Comment: The `Move window one monitor up` has the right shortcut but it is a bad choice. I would like to know why it happened. Is this a mistake or a bad decision?

Comment: Actually, I realized that `Super`+`Page_Up` also changes the workspace now. So `Shift`+`Super`+`Page_Up` makes sense.